# Java pong can't move both paddles at once

Tags: java, swing, game-development, keylistener, pong

I want to create a pong game where players move 2 paddles with w-s and up-down keys

I'm creating a pong game in java with swing and the graphics. My idea is that two players play game one on the same keyboard with the W-S and UP-DOWN keys to move the racket left and right respectively. When implementing it I got stuck since the two rackets cannot be moved at the same time, if you press W the racket on the left moves but the one on the right cannot be moved until you release the w, the same happens with the buttons on the shovel on the right I put the rackets in 2 different threads but the problem continues and it seems to me that it is because of the KeyListener.

I leave you the important parts of the shovel and window class.

Key listener:

```
public Ventana() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Pong");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        jugador1 = new Raqueta(this, Raqueta.JUGADOR1);
        jugador2 = new Raqueta(this, Raqueta.JUGADOR2);
        
        jugador1.start();
        jugador2.start();
                
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) { 
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        
        
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        jugador1.dibujar(g);
        jugador2.dibujar(g);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                jugador1.moverY(Raqueta.SUBIR);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                jugador1.moverY(Raqueta.BAJAR);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                jugador2.moverY(Raqueta.SUBIR);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                jugador2.moverY(Raqueta.BAJAR);
                break;
        }
        
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                jugador1.moverY(Raqueta.PARAR);
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                jugador2.moverY(Raqueta.PARAR);
        }
    }
```

The racket:

```
public class Raqueta extends Thread{
    private int x, y, anchura, altura;
    private byte direccion;
    public final static byte BAJAR = 0;
    public final static byte SUBIR = 1;
    public final static byte PARAR = -1;
    public final static byte JUGADOR1 = 1;
    public final static byte JUGADOR2 = 2;
    

    public void setDireccion(byte direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                moverY(direccion);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    public void moverY(byte x) {
        if (x == BAJAR){
            this.y = y + 10;
        } else if (x == SUBIR){
            this.y = y - 10;
        }
    }
    
    public void dibujar(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getAnchura(), getAltura());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `break;` commands  inside `keyReleased`.

Comment: Although it looks as though `keyReleased` does nothing.

Comment: Use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of key listeners.  Your key bindings should set values and your game loop should process those values and do the actual movement.

Comment: *with the W-S and UP-DOWN keys to move the racket left and right respectively* Check out the `KeyboardAnimation` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for an example.